# Multivariate map

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a multivariate function that I want to map into a triple of variables.

```
x = {0.01`, 0.11`, 0.21000000000000002`, 0.31000000000000005`, 
   0.41000000000000003`, 0.51`, 0.6100000000000001`, 
   0.7100000000000001`, 0.81`, 0.91`};
y = {1.`, 1.`, 1.`, 1.`, 1.`, 0.9804148800744802`, 
   0.8196730260718126`, 0.6189620070242443`, 0.40469250572443105`, 
   0.26901189545273474`};
z = {0.8153370522348216`, 0.8853249359665971`, 0.9223317847713025`, 
   0.9559380865485229`, 0.9999999995185327`, 1.`, 1.`, 
   0.9084506972387802`, 0.7345679056105409`, 0.5989011012000781`};
domain = Partition[Flatten[{x, y, z}], 3];

f[x_, y_, z_] := (x + 1.5*y + 1.2*z)/(1 + x);

Map[f, domain]
```

I want

```
{f[0.01, 0.11, 0.21], f[0.31, 0.41, 0.51], f[0.61, 0.71, 0.81], 
 f[0.91, 0.815337, 0.885325], f[0.922332, 0.955938, 1.], 
 f[1., 1., 0.908451], f[0.734568, 0.598901, 1.], f[1., 1., 1.], 
 f[1., 0.980415, 0.819673], f[0.618962, 0.404693, 0.269012]}
```

But for some reason when I Map[f, domain] I get:

```
{f[{0.01, 0.11, 0.21}], f[{0.31, 0.41, 0.51}], f[{0.61, 0.71, 0.81}], 
 f[{0.91, 0.815337, 0.885325}], f[{0.922332, 0.955938, 1.}], 
 f[{1., 1., 0.908451}], f[{0.734568, 0.598901, 1.}], f[{1., 1., 1.}], 
 f[{1., 0.980415, 0.819673}], f[{0.618962, 0.404693, 0.269012}]}
```

I have searched the documentation and other posts, but I still cannot figure what is going on with this very simple problem.

Comment: Either define `f[{x_, y_, z_}]:=....`, or do `Apply[f, domain, 1]` (in short-hand notation: `f @@@ domain`).

Comment: Would say  that looks like to form triplets as mydom=Thread[{x,y,z}]

Comment: Or this domain=Transpose@{x, y, z}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and  work as , I think, you expect

```
    x = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 10];
    y = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 10];
    z = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 10];
    mydom = Thread[{x, y, z}];
    Apply[f, mydom, 2]
```

Comment: Of course. Thank you so much, @AnxonPues.

Comment: And also thank you for using the `RandomInteger` to create a better example than mine!

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. `f @@@ domain` is all you need.

```
f @@@ domain
```

> `{0.422772, 1.17328, 1.6441, 1.89005, 1.85, 1.49094, 1.27189, 1.81186, 1.85, 1.42995}`

Comment: Of course! Thank you so much, @m_goldberg!